# Can lsof show open ports on alpine linux?

Tags: linux, networking, port, alpine-linux, lsof

I have a spring boot app running in alpine linux listening on port 8080. However, when I do:

```
$ lsof
$ lsof -i 8080
```

it doesn't show the open ports. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

It almost seems that lsof on alpine linux isn't honoring any arguments. It always shows the same output - just seems to ignore -i.

[image: p]

[image]

Comment: try use `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Install `lsof` from [lsof](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.4/main/x86/lsof), not from busybox. Busyboxs lsof is just only [simple](https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/procps/lsof.c).

```
apk add lsof
```

should fix it.

Comment: any alternative to installing additional packages?

Comment: `any alternative to installing additional packages? ` No. Shell is just a tool to run other programs - without other programs, there is nothing to run. Instead of "installing" you can compile it yourself.